# CKEDITOR, Image Upload in jsp pages

Tags: java, jsp, file-upload, ckeditor

I've been looking for a tutorial on this matter but all of them are using php. I need to integrate an image uploader for ckeditor in jsp pages using java code. if someone could help me out or direct me to a tutorial, I'll be very thankfull.

Answer (score 0):

... don't have a direct answer to that, but here's some tidbit I found useful ( and if it's a really - really improper way to handle this, please correct me).

I already had the image upload functionality working before I thought about adding an editor. The thumbnails were displayed in a row.

Then I added an editor ( and by the way, it worked in all the ones I tested ), CK or another one.

After that, while in the WYSIWYG mode of the editor, I can just click and drag a thumbnail into the editor and there it is. The thumbnail sits in the editor.

Also, I just found this: [CKEditor for Java Released!
Added by Anna, 02 May 2011](http://ckeditor.com/blog/CKEditor_for_Java_released)